# How to display pdf on picture box in access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to display pdf on picture box in access
If I set picture on picture box, there is the error 
How can I show pdf on picture box?
Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

A picture box is (surprisingly as its name tells) to show pictures and not PDF files.
You cannot load a PDF into a picture box.